# Using GROUP BY clause on EPOCH time on mysql table

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, epoch, infobright

I have a few million records in the mysql table **TEST**.

One of the column (**TRIAL_TIME**) of **TEST** table stores EPOCH time as BIGINT. A sql query is fired which uses **GROUP BY** clause to group data on the TRIAL_TIME.

The query is something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(A1), COUNT(B1) 
from TEST 
WHERE <some clause> 
GROUP BY TRIAL_TIME DIV 300000 
ORDER BY <some column>;
```

300000 in the above query indicates the time I would like to group the data with. SO for example, if I had like to group data by 1 minute, I would use 60000. The query then becomes

```
SELECT SUM(A1), COUNT(B1) 
from TEST 
WHERE <some clause> 
GROUP BY TRIAL_TIME DIV 600000 
ORDER BY <some column>;
```

Question is

1. Will this be an efficient query?
2. If no , what would be a better approach?
3. Open to use ALTER table to accommodate a better solution.

One of the possible solution could be to add new column and parse the EPOCH time to extract DATE, TIME etc field and update the newly created columns with the appropriate values so that **GROUP BY** becomes easier.

Wondering if this is a wise solution?

NOTE - For the record use mysql 5.1 and Infobright engine. The current query uses about 3 minutes to execute (because of the GROUP BY CLAUSE). The performance goal is to bring it under 30 seconds.

Comment: Why is an epoch time stored in a BIGINT when TIMESTAMP is designed for the purpose

Comment: That has come in as a legacy thing. No control over it. But are u saying storing as date time will help?

Comment: No just thinking if its worth the risk of offereing an answer. If such a simple mistake has been made, am I just going to stumble about in the mire

Comment: Have you got an index on TRIAL_TIME?

Comment: Nopes. It comes in sorted.

Comment: Show us an example of what is really in this EPOCH time field

Comment: I think his "epoch" is in milliseconds, hence `BIGINT` does work.  But, so would `TIMESTAMP(3)`.

Comment: For infobright, I doubt if an index or order of insert matters for `TRIAL_TIME`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here are a few from the TRIAL_TIME columns - 1456497954591, 1456497954594,1456497954596 . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ... -- With a good index, this _might_ be less of a problem; otherwise it needs scan
GROUP BY FLOOR(ts/300000) -- adding a column will not help
ORDER BY something_else -- this will force [another] sort
```

How many rows are you scanning?  If it is a large number, it is not reasonable to expect high speed without having some form of Summary table.

You mentioned Infobright, but you have not mentioned which key 'preferred' in the storage of the data.  Infobright will skip chunks of 64K rows that do not match the `WHERE` clause; are you taking advantage of that?  If not, all relevant columns need to be unpacked from all chunks.

[Summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) -- however, it was not written with Infobright in mind.